# Make lines blink inside a canvas

Tags: javascript, canvas, lines, kineticjs, blink

I'm currently working on a HTML5 and Javascript project using [Kinetic Js](http://www.kineticjs.com/) and canvas.

I need my lines (`Kinetic.Line`) to blink.

I've tried something consisting of an infinite loop with `setTimeout` function inside, but I can't use javascript then (such a drawback because then I can't select points!).

Does somebody have an idea that can help me?

```
while (1) {
setTimeout("stage.load(myjson[0])", 1000);
setTimeout("stage.load(myjson[1])", 1000);
}
```

*(sorry for my poor english)*

Comment: @FlorianMargaine I don't think the `blink` tag might help in any way in this situation...

Comment: @Chips_100 Nope, it was rather for fun :]

Comment: Can you show what you've tried?  My first thought is to alternate drawing the line using its color and the background color to emulate blinking.

Comment: @CMKanode I've just added this in my first post. I think the `stage.load` method is memory-greedy... But i'm not enjoying the fact i have to draw my line as many time as required!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's one way of making a line blink using KineticJS. Rather than using setTimeout, I think it's better to use the KineticJS onFrame event which is built into the stage object. You can then use setAlpha to set the opacity of the line, and getAlpha to get the current opacity of the line. setAlpha('0') will make the line transparent, setAlpha('1') will make the line visible.

I've set up a fiddle here:
[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/QfEUP/1/)

Here's the relevant bit that actually flashes the line:

```
var flashTime = 0;

stage.onFrame(function(frame){
    if(frame.time > (flashTime + 250)){;
        flashTime = frame.time;
        redLine.setAlpha(redLine.getAlpha() == 1 ? '0' : '1');
        layer.draw();                                
    };                                        
});
```